# "Visual imperfection" and "cosmetic flaw" in description of an item for sale

Tags: meaning, semantics

Some online retailers sell "second quality" items at a discounted price. These items usually have some sort of defect that makes them unsuitable for sale at the normal price, but typically they are still functional/decent-looking/etc. (Second quality items are also sometimes known as "factory seconds" or simply "seconds.")

If a retailer is selling a second quality item which it describes as having a "visual imperfection" or "cosmetic flaw" (and **no mention of any other defects**), would you say that a customer should take this to mean that the item could reasonably be expected to have a defect that makes it less durable and more prone to break? Or would the presence of such a defect require further specification on the part of the seller?

Another way of looking at this is: If a retailer is selling an item known to possess a defect making it more prone to break, is it reasonable for the retailer to describe the item as having a "visual imperfection"/"cosmetic flaw" (with no mention of any other defects)?

Edits/Addenda:

In response to some of the comments:

*@MarcInManhattan: "I don't understand why the mention of one kind of flaw would necessarily imply the existence of any other kind of flaw."*

This comment seems to miss the point. The question is NOT whether the term implies **any other kind** of flaw; the question is whether a flaw that makes the item more prone to breakage is included within the range of what is generally meant by "visual imperfection." IF it is included, then this wouldn't be "another kind" of flaw; it would be part of the same category.

*@cruthers: "I don't know what 'second quality' is - I don't think that term is in common use"*

The term "second quality" is common enough. A simple Google search reveals plenty of online retailers using the term on their sites. It's often (but not exclusively) used in reference to handmade, artisanal products that may be more prone to variation from item to item. Second quality items are sometimes called "factory seconds" or just "seconds." I made sure to include a brief explanation of the term in my question in anticipation of the fact that some people might not be familiar with it.

*@aparente001: "I'd say, if in doubt, ask the seller."*

Thanks for the advice, but that was actually the very first thing I did. You must be a genius, just like me, to have come up *the same brilliant idea*! The outcome of that is not particularly relevant to the question that I posted, as the seller explicitly refused to provide further clarification about the nature of the defect, as a matter of policy. I haven't bought anything from the seller, and, as far as I'm concerned, this is not a legal question, like @Peter suggested. My question is motivated by personal curiosity about what the generally accepted meaning of these terms is.

Answer (score 3):

These terms generally mean that the problem with the object is purely esthetic, it shouldn't have any significant effect on the function that the product is intended to perform.

Of course, if the purpose of the product includes visual appeal, there's some overlap. For instance, clothing is usually intended to look good, and it won't look as good if it has a cosmetic flaw. But the flaw shouldn't cause the clothing to fall apart.

This isn't really the place to give advice on purchasing damaged goods, but you might consider that whatever caused the product to have these minor imperfections might also have damaged the mechanism, but the seller isn't aware of it (or is deliberately downplaying it). The visual flaws might just be the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Right, because if the imperfection makes it prone to breakage, it is a very serious flaw, selling-wise.

Comment: It depends on the product. A flaw in the paint job of a car could allow for rust at that spot. But a flaw in the printing of a T-shirt doesn't mean the fabric will unravel.

Comment: Yes, a flaw in a paint job is a twofer. :)